# The target object email address is currently marked as bounced

Tags: email, apex-email-service, bounce-management

I have activated bounce management in two dev orgs. I am sending emails to record owner through batch class. If email is not valid, DEV1 org is throwing a message `Email address is invalid` and DEV2 org is throwing `The target object email address is currently marked as bounced`.

I want `The target object email address is currently marked as bounced` message in both orgs. Is there any configuration missing in DEV1 org.